# vuejs application does not run with dockerized npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a repeatable build-environment which does not mess with anything on the local machine. For that I decided to use docker to wrap the `npm` and `vue` cli. Everything runs on the machine where I first ran the vue quickstart command.

But when I take a fresh clone from the repository on another machine, I get the following error after running the setup process:

```
$ ./npm run dev

> my-project@1.0.0 dev /data
> node build/dev-server.js

module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/data/build/dev-server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:148:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-project@1.0.0 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@1.0.0 dev script 'node build/dev-server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-project package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/dev-server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-project
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-project
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /data/npm-debug.log
```

It says that details are in `/data/npm-debug.log` but I can't see that file either. So both the `build` folder and `npm-debug.log` seem to never appear on the mounted volume. I guess something with my docker setup is not quite right. But I don't know what.

To reproduce the following error run the following:

**NOTE** You need to hav "fabric" installed for the 4th step. If you don't have it, look at the contents of `fabfile.py`, it's really easy to understand and run the tasks manually.

**NOTE2** If you don't have python 3 with "pyvenv", the `fab develop` task will fail on the last step of the `develop` task. You can ignore this for this docker/npm issue as the Python portion is not needed.

```
git clone https://github.com/exhuma/powonline
cd powonline
git checkout stackoverflow-2017-06-17
fab develop
cd frontend
./npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The "build" folder was in the `.gitignore` file. It should not have been.

I mistakenly took that folder as a folder with built artifacts while it contains configuration files for the build process. Hence it should not be ignored and must be part of the repository. I have since added it to the repository and the process has become repeatable without problems.